# How to prove $\forall x\; (\phi (x)\land \psi (x) ) \rightarrow \forall x\; \psi (x)$ without using the completeness theorem?

Tags: proof-writing, model-theory, provability

The statement $\forall x\; (\phi (x)\land \psi (x) ) \rightarrow \forall x\; \psi (x)$ is valid, that is it is true in any structure. Hence, for any $\sum \subseteq Form_{\mathcal{L}}\; \sum \models \forall x\; (\phi (x)\land \psi (x) ) \rightarrow \forall x\; \psi (x)$. This, by completeness theorem, implies that for all $\sum \subseteq Form_{\mathcal{L}}\; \sum \vdash \forall x\; (\phi (x)\land \psi (x) ) \rightarrow \forall x\; \psi (x)$. However, this answer didn’t satisfied me. I look for an answer in which completeness theorem not included. Because I don’t want the manipulation rules to be involved in the metatheory.

Comment: hi boyler. this sentence is in fact not valid; consider for example the case when $\phi(x)=\psi(x)$. then $\forall x(\phi(x)\to\psi(x))$ is always true but $\forall x\psi(x)$ may or may not be

Comment: Oh sorry, i had a typo, i fixed it now

Comment: If you don't want to use a semantic argument, you need to tell us what proof system you're using.

Comment: I am using the book “A friendly introduction to mathematical logic” by Leary. Here is the link https://milneopentextbooks.org/a-friendly-introduction-to-mathematical-logic/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a direct proof using the system in your book.

1. $(\forall x\, (\phi(x)\land \psi(x)))\to (\phi(x)\land \psi(x))\quad$ (Q1, substituting $x$ for $x$)
2. $(\forall x\, (\phi(x)\land \psi(x)))\to \psi(x)\quad$  (Propositional logic, from 1)
3. $(\forall x\, (\phi(x)\land \psi(x)))\to \forall x\,\psi(x)\quad$ (QR, from 2, since $x$ is not free in $\forall x\, (\phi(x)\land \psi(x))$)